# How to fix AR Core Issue in Native Integration?

Tags: android, arcore

I am integrating ARcore sceneform in my Android Native Project . I am facing below issue while opening camera. It happens some times only . I am not able to find the exact issue .

```
E/third_party/arcore/ar/sceneform/android/jni/arsceneview_jni.cc: nativeReportEngineType: Couldn't get session's nativeHandle
2019-05-15 19:30:28.411 22577-22577/com.innovare.plugxr 

E/NdkImageReader: AImageReader_getWindow
2019-05-15 19:30:28.600 22577-22577/com.innovare.plugxr 

E/native: session.cc:1527 Invalid ray produced by view data!
2019-05-15 19:30:28.850 22577-22577/com.innovare.plugxr 

A/libc: Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 1, fault addr 0x728e1b48 in tid 22577 (innovare.plugxr)
```